Using bovine insulin in bovine cell culture for diabetics
Insulin in the US is very expensive. It uses DNA recombinant techniques on yeast or bacteria, which requires patented techniques to isolate the insulin.
In contrast, bovine cell culture of the bovine pancreas may allow the (relatively) easy production of bovine insulin from the cells, in a manner that does not require patented filtration techniques.
Given the expensive cost of human insulin in the US, could bovine insulin made by individual small-scale labs be a feasible alternative?

Insulin is pretty cheap everywhere else. I don't think there are technical reasons why it's expensive in the US, it's just that country's broken health system.

Besides that, insulin from pigs has been used for decades until it was replaced by human insulin from biotech. As fas as I know, there are less side effects now.

I'd suggest reading up on the history of insulin. Until the 1980s all insulin came from pig and cow pancreases. It took tons of pancreases to generate a few ounces of insulin. That was feasible, because we slaughter a lot of pigs and cows for food. Maintaining mammalian tissue cultures requires skilled labor and a laboratory with excellent quality control standards. You aren't going to do it in a garage, and it will produce minuscule amounts of insulin. Today's insulin is made in giant vats of E. coli. Growing vats of bacteria at industrial scale is pretty much a solved problem.

@CharlesE.Grant I see, so there's no question about using E. coli. This might be unrelated, but is there a reason why projects such as the Open Insulin Project aren't taking off?

@terdon The way I see it, there is no way to decrease US medical prices across the board unless independent, individually producible competition is created. The current price of medicine makes it cheaper (even accounting for human labor, precursors, and perhaps even equipment) to make one's medicines than to buy it from a company. Purificiation is the only step where I see concerns.

@Chris I see. Thank you for the input!

I'm not familiar with Open Insulin. I just read their web page. I suspect they suffer from the problems many inventors face in going from a "proof of concept" project to mass market scaling. Reliable, cost effective, manufacturing with effective quality control is often much harder than simply getting the clever innovation to work on a demonstration scale. You can easily kill people with insulin, and you have to make the process utterly reliable in the hands of ordinary people. Many biohackers are fairly casual about their own safety, but they want to provide this to ordinary end users.

@CharlesE.Grant Yes, its the costs of certification (if it is a drug for distribution then you need FDA registration etc. in the USA) and GMP that make it unlikely for any of these small scale operations to be feasible.

@bob1 I see... Saddening that waivers cannot be signed even

In Estonia there was GMO cow project where human insulin genes were transferred to cow milk secretion area to later extract insulin from milk. I'm not sure if there is any progress in that field.
